# Error while plotting data in rchart using HighChart

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I am reading data from file and plotting data using rchart/highchart but i am getting following Error.

sampledata

```
A   B   C
2   3   0
4   5   0
4   -3   1
-8   5   1
2   -3   2
-2   -5   2
12   3   3
-4   5   3
```

R Scitpt:

```
require(devtools)
install_github(’rCharts’ ,’ramnathv’)
sampledata<-read.csv("data.csv",header=TRUE,sep="\t")
h1 <- hPlot(x = sampledata[1,], y = sampledata[2,], data = sampledata, type = "scatter", group=sampledata[3,])
```

Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : invalid subscript type 'list'

How can i plot scatter plot using rcharts by calling Highcharts internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your column names in the sampledata are A, B and C, this should work:

```
h1 <- hPlot(x = 'A', y = 'B', data = sampledata, type = "scatter", group='C')
```

Function `hPlot` does not want to get the actual data values. Instead, you should give as an input the names of columns you want to plot. Alternatively, you can also use a formula interface. For example, see, https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/inst/libraries/highcharts/examples.R.