# How to include Rchart image in web page?

Tags: html, r, highcharts, rcharts

This refers to my previos question.

[Error while plotting data in rchart using HighChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034099/error-while-plotting-data-in-rchart-using-highchart/27034502#27034502)

Input data

```
data.csv

A   B   C
2   3   0
4   5   0
4   -3   1
-8   5   1
2   -3   2
-2   -5   2
12   3   3
-4   5   3
```

Rchart code:

```
require(devtools)
install_github(’rCharts’ ,’ramnathv’)
sampledata<-read.csv("data.csv",header=TRUE,sep="\t")
h1 <- hPlot(x = sampledata[1,], y = sampledata[2,], data = sampledata, type = "scatter", group=sampledata[3,])
h1 <- hPlot(x = 'A', y = 'B', data = sampledata, type = "scatter", group='C') 

Chart can be save to html format using following command 
h1$save('mychart.html', cdn  = TRUE)
```

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=05456920443055569002

Now i can generate Rchart using HighChart but now i need to show that image in one section of HTML page (in Section Code) shown below. How can i implement it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style>
header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;     
}
nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:300px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;          
}
section {
    width:350px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;        
}
footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;         
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<header>
<h1>City Gallery</h1>
</header>

<nav>
London<br>
Paris<br>
Tokyo<br>
</nav>

<section>
<h1>Image</h1>
**Need  to include dynamic image here**
</section>

<footer>
Copyright © W3Schools.com
</footer>

</body>
```

Comment: can you create fiddle with Rchart using HighChart

Comment: I am not really aware about fiddie.

Comment: i need a code for Rchart using HighChart?? or add the id to chart and use same id in the html, it will add

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa I have edited my question and added Rchart/High Chart code and input data.

Comment: I don't know how to add id to code as this is R code.

Comment: can you post the highchart code atleast??

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y1jf6brm/ this the chart, now you need to call this  `container ` id in your rchart

Comment: Code i posted is complete code. I am calling highchart from Rchart

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa your example is great but i need to save dynamatic chart generated from Rchart. I have edited my question and added one line for sacing plot in HTML format which generates HighChart code embeded in plain HTML page. Is there any way to parse the code and add in my web page.

Comment: i hope you can do ajax request if it is a dynamic request.

Comment: Can u pls send me any link for the same or same example.